# Расширить LVM диск

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

Есть сервер zabbix в виртуальной среде (hyper-v) под ubuntu. Стало заканчивать свободное место на диске. Виртуальный жесткий диск был расширен, но не получается расширить lvm диск в ubuntu.

```
df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        395M  5.5M  389M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/zabbix--vg-root   15G   12G  2.5G  83% /
tmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    1.5G  689M  689M  50% /boot

pvs

PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda3  zabbix-vg lvm2 a--  10.23g    0
  /dev/sda5  zabbix-vg lvm2 a--  38.30g    0

vgs

VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  zabbix-vg   2   2   0 wz--n- 48.53g    0

lvs

LV     VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   zabbix-vg -wi-ao---- 44.53g
  swap_1 zabbix-vg -wi-ao----  4.00g
```

Comment: Разметка Mbr или gpt?

Comment: @eri, разметка mbr

Comment: что именно не получается? если перезагрузка допустима, то мжно так: `fdisk`'ом изменяешь размер последнего раздела -> перезагружаешься -> `pvresize`'ом изменяешь размер физ. тома, а затем `lvresize`'ом изменяшь размер лог. томом как необходимо...

Comment: Судя по скринам не хватает команды что у меня в ответе последняя

Comment: В буте ещё почисти, 600 м это много. Лишние ядра валяются

Comment: @Fat-Zer судя по тексту lv растянул, а фс нет

Comment: да... похоже на то... я что-то проглядел это...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По пунктам:

Выключаешь виртуалку.

Добавляешь место на виртуальный диск.

Включаешь виртуалку

Создаешь новый раздел на свободном месте через gdisk, fdisk. Можно растянуть последний раздел через parted, но плюсов это не даст.

Форматируешь раздел в lvm PV или при растягивании - pvresize

Добавляешь PV в VG

Растягиваешь LV на свободное место  VG, тут возможно придётся перезагрузиться.

Растягиваешь файлувую систему на размер LV

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/zabbix--vg-root
```

Comment: Да, все сделал, только не растянул файловую систему, спасибо!